# How do I swap the coordinates Y,X to coordinates X,Y in a list?

Tags: python, folium

How do I go about swapping the coordinates around from Y, X to X, Y in a list that contain multiple of list? (see geojson below)

Currently, I retrieve a geojson file that contains a list of coordinates from the overpass turbo and I would like to plot a path using the folium polyline using the list of coordinates from my geojson file. However, I notice the coordinates in geojson file is in longitude, latitude instead of latitude, longitude. Therefore the polyline is not appearring on my map.

Below are my code and I have tried swapping the coordinates. However, the coordinate is still not being swapped

**CODE**

```
with open('BusPath/BusService.geojson') as access_json:
        read_content = json.load(access_json)
        bus_access = read_content['features']

    for bus_data in bus_access:
        busName = bus_data['properties']
        if busPath == busName['name']:
            busCoord = [v[::-1] for v in bus_data['geometry']['coordinates']]
            print(busCoord)

folium.PolyLine(busCoord, opacity=1, color='red').add_to(self.m)
data = io.BytesIO()
self.m.save(data, close_file=False)
self.view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())


#Output of print(busCoord)
[[[103.9060467, 1.3991345], [103.9058912, 1.3992605], [103.9056954, 1.3994], [103.9053896, 1.3996064], [103.9052668, 1.3996311], [103.9051645, 1.399626], [103.905072, 1.3995938], [103.9049717, 1.3995537], [103.9046416, 1.3988584], [103.9044522, 1.3984454], [103.9042792, 1.3980713]]]
```

**JSON FILE** As you can see there are multiple lists containing coordinates of the path, which is contain in a main list call "coordinates"

```
"geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              103.9060467,
              1.3991345
            ],
            [
              103.9058912,
              1.3992605
            ],
            [
              103.9056954,
              1.3994
            ],
            [
              103.9053896,
              1.3996064
            ],
            [
              103.9052668,
              1.3996311
            ],
            [
              103.9051645,
              1.399626
            ],
            [
              103.905072,
              1.3995938
            ],
            [
              103.9049717,
              1.3995537
            ],
            [
              103.9046416,
              1.3988584
            ],
            [
              103.9044522,
              1.3984454
            ],
            [
              103.9042792,
              1.3980713
            ],
            [
              103.9041011,
              1.3977284
            ],
            [
              103.9040748,
              1.3975609
            ],
            [
              103.9040403,
              1.3974097
            ],
            [
              103.9040419,
              1.3973301
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              103.910618,
              1.3954313
            ],
            [
              103.9096382,
              1.3962145
            ],
            [
              103.9084619,
              1.3971647
            ],
            [
              103.9079136,
              1.3976289
            ],
            [
              103.9077352,
              1.3977763
            ],
            [
              103.9073965,
              1.3980253
            ],
            [
              103.9072047,
              1.398188
            ],
            [
              103.9071445,
              1.3982345
            ],
            [
              103.9068999,
              1.3984727
            ]
          ],
          [
            [
              103.9023155,
              1.4034919
            ],
            [
              103.9022324,
              1.4036635
            ],
            [
              103.9022109,
              1.4037547
            ],
            [
              103.9022109,
              1.403819
            ],
            [
              103.9024009,
              1.4041775
            ],
            [
              103.9026193,
              1.4045984
            ],
            [
              103.9026671,
              1.4046228
            ],
            [
              103.9028788,
              1.4044948
            ],
            [
              103.9023155,
              1.4034919
            ],
            [
              103.9025304,
              1.403368
            ],
            [
              103.9026886,
              1.4032743
            ],
            [
              103.9029776,
              1.4031102
            ],
            [
              103.902983,
              1.4031189
            ],
            [
              103.9033585,
              1.4037261
            ],
            [
              103.9034812,
              1.4039168
            ],
            [
              103.9036107,
              1.4041337
            ],
            [
              103.9037633,
              1.4043804
            ],
            [
              103.9038275,
              1.4044809
            ],
            [
              103.9039067,
              1.4044437
            ],
            [
              103.904112,
              1.4043433
            ],
            [
              103.9047004,
              1.4040091
            ],
            [
              103.9049444,
              1.4038705
            ],
            [
              103.9052092,
              1.4036879
            ],
            [
              103.9055394,
              1.4034604
            ],
            [
              103.9056471,
              1.4033926
            ],
            [
              103.9059194,
              1.4032213
            ],
            [
              103.9062514,
              1.4029677
            ],
            [
              103.9063671,
              1.4028932
            ],
            [
              103.9065893,
              1.4027593
            ],
            [
              103.9071575,
              1.4023613
            ],
            [
              103.9072297,
              1.4023108
            ],
            [
              103.9077716,
              1.40193
            ],
            [
              103.9083671,
              1.4014838
            ],
            [
              103.9085667,
              1.4013343
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinate list is too deep, instead of:

```
busCoord = [v[::-1] for v in bus_data['geometry']['coordinates']]
```

you should have tried:

```
busCoord = [v[::-1] for v in bus_data['geometry']['coordinates'][0]]
```

to get to the actual coordinates. Your current code is reversing the outermost list that has only 1 element -- the list of the coordinates.

Comment: hmm okay the issue is my coordinates contain a couple of list in the main list. Let me update my json file again.

Comment: So uhm as in the JSON file, the coordinates list, contain a couple of additional list which contain the coordinates.

Comment: @DeniseTay I don't understand what you say. Could you please ask a question?

Comment: Sorry, ohm as you can see from my JSON file format, there are multiple lists contain coordinates in  the coordinates list. The code you have kindly provided only plot the path of the first list of coordinates, not the entire list